# I want to add open graph image on blog page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2

I need to add an image in open graph image meta tag in head section on a blog page. Can somebody how I can achieve this.

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $post = $this->getPost();
        $this->_addBreadcrumbs($post);
        $this->pageConfig->addBodyClass('blog-post-' . $post->getIdentifier());
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set($post->getTitle());
        $this->pageConfig->setKeywords($post->getMetaKeywords());
        $this->pageConfig->setDescription($post->getMetaDescription());
        ?><head><meta property="og:image" content="https://turner-sports.co.uk/pub/media/blog/punch_bag_blog_featured_image_1.png" /></head><?php


        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide me the name of blog extension you are using?

Comment: I am using Magefan Blog extensions.Here is link of a blog page.https://turner-sports.co.uk/blog/post/is-bigger-punch-bag-is-always-better.html/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your extension already have og:image tag option.
Goto below file location:

> app/code/Magefan/Blog/view/frontend/templates/post/view/opengraph.phtml

Check the below condition:

```
<?php if ($image = $block->getImage()) { ?>
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($image); ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

If you have image then only this tag will render. Check it and add your image then it will show.

UPDATED ANSWER:
Update your module to latest version. You can find out the latest version:

> https://github.com/magefan/module-blog

Also you need to install

> https://github.com/magefan/module-community

which is dependent module of blog extension.

Comment: Currently i cant see opengraph.phtml in module.But i am adding it with above code you sent to me.  https://ibb.co/jEfZx9

Comment: Check my updated answer. I think you are using old version, you need to update your module.

Comment: Thanks A Lot buddy i am updating to new version.Hopefully it solve the issue.

Comment: Welcome. If its working for you then tick the green mark near the answer .

Comment: Yes problem Solved